# Running a C++ code on multiple (~9k) files separately in a go

Tags: c++, file-handling

I think that the code is irrelevant to the question so, if you think it is necessary at any point of time, then please mention. I can readily share the snippets.

I wrote a code for a project that uses 3 files :

1. Input file (*.pdb*)
2. Temporary Intermediate (say *xyz.txt*)
3. Output (*.txt*)

For each input file, the program creates a separate output file. Also, it uses a temporary intermediate file *xyz.txt* for the process. *xyz.txt* can be the same for all files. But the issue is that I want to run the code for approximately 9000 files & it would be ridiculous to do that individually for each file.

Is there any way I could do this task simultaneously? My code asks for the location of input, *xyz* and output file. Temporarily, I've created a file *output.txt* where I save the output.

```
cout << "Enter the absolute path to the input file:";
cin >> inputf;
fin.open(inputf);
if ( fin.fail() ) {
    cerr << "Could not open .pdb file " << inputf << endl;
    exit(1);
    }

cout << "Enter the absolute path to a intermediate file (say xyz):";
cin >> xyz;
fout.open(xyz);
if ( fout.fail() ) {
    cerr << "Could not open xyz file " << xyz << endl;
    exit(1);
    }

// some irrelevant code goes here

cout << "Enter the absolute path to the final output file:";
cin >> inputf;
fout.open(inputf);
if ( fout.fail() ) {
    cerr << "Could not open output file " << inputf << endl;
    exit(1);
    }
```

I want the name of the output file to be same as the input file. (say) Input file is *example.pdb* then output file should be named *example.txt*.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: if you intend to type in all the filenames by hand, then make an `std::vector` and in a loop (`for` or `while`) collect all the names, then start the processing on each of them

Comment: the better way would be to have all files with a similar name (differing in a number for example) and then you can generate the filenames from you code, without prompting anything

Comment: Note that since C++17 STL algorithms have now extra parameter `ExecutionPolicy`. This should be useful.

Comment: I wish that the folder in which I have saved all the input files could be given as input with something like *.pdb so that it runs for all the files ending in .pdb notation. I can't individually write filenames by hand. Also, this similar name option is very nice but the project dosen't allow perturbations with the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is perform the processesing in parallel and then write to the disk sequentially (since you *can* only right to the disk sequentially). You can also get rid of the tempory files and process big files in chuncks. Any processing your doing on the tempory file can be replaced by something (i.e a class) which records changes and applies them to the the output stream.

Writing to the disk can be done using a buffer/synchronisation class, an instance of which is passed between threads and which writes each change to the disk in full before processing the next one. This is the cleanest way of doing it and although possibly not needed to avoid data races (since you are only reading from input files and only writing to a single output per thread), it will make your design clearer and enable expandability in the future (also prevents the file from being scattered in the case of hard drives). [Asio](https://think-async.com/Asio/) is a library designed for asynchrouse I/O and comes equiped with thread pools, asynchronise file handling and many more useful things which means you (mostly) don't have to worry about the things I said above.

Unless you are doing some very computationally complex task however, the disk will still be your bottleneck. Again depending on your programs processing complexity this solution may only yeild mininal gains.

As a side note you can calculate the output filename from the input filename by using the `stem()` method of an `std::filesystem::path`. Like this:

```cpp
std::filesystem::path my_path("foo.txt");
std::filesystem::path my_output_path(my_path.stem()+std::filesystem::path(".my_extension"));
```